# TASKS history in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a efficient way to see the logs of task run in snowflake

I am using this. Is there a possibility to wipe off the history from here?

```
select *
  from table(information_schema.task_history(
    scheduled_time_range_start=>dateadd('hour',-1,current_timestamp()),
    result_limit => 1000,
    task_name=>'TASKNAME'));
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a efficient way to see the logs of task run in Snowflake?*

Depending of meaning of workd efficient, Snowflake offers UI to monitor  tasks dependencies and run history.

[Run History](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-tasks.html#run-history)

> Task run history includes details about each execution of a given task. You can view the scheduled time, the actual start time, duration of a task and other information.

[Account Level Task History](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight-tasks.html#account-level-task-history):

> ask history displays task information at the account level, and is divided into three sections:
>
> Selection (1) - Defines the set of task history to display, and includes types of tasks, date range and other information
>
> Histogram (2) - Displays a bar graph of task runs over.
>
> Task list (3) - a list of selected tasks.

---

> *Is there a possibility to wipe off the history from here?*

[Task History](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/task_history.html)

> This Account Usage view enables you to retrieve the history of task usage within the last 365 days (1 year). The view displays one row for each run of a task in the history.